# Program hanging while running, compiles well

Tags: c++, const-char

EDITED :

```
     #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

void dfsvisit(int a[][30], int i, const char *color[])
     {
        int v;
        int p[30];
        int f[30]={};
        static int j=1;
        color[i]="gray";

        for(v=1;v<31;v++)
            while(a[i][v]!=0)
                if(!strcmp(color[a[i][v]],"white"))
                    {
                        p[a[i][v]]=i;
                        dfsvisit(a,i,color);
                    }

        color[i]="black";
        j++;
        f[i]=1;
        cout<<f[i]<<" ";
     }

int main()
{
    int a[][30]={{2, 16},{4, 8},{5, 16, 21},{1, 2},{1, 9, 27},{1, 10, 15},{4, 6, 11, 12},{4, 16},{2, 19, 29},{3, 14, 28},{3, 13, 15, 17},{8, 9, 18, 26},{1, 7, 10, 19},{5, 8, 20, 24},{3, 21, 29},{1, 2, 8},{16, 23, 28, 29},{4, 12, 21, 24},   {3, 15, 16},{2, 3, 6, 22},{4, 15, 25},{4, 6, 20, 24},{9, 10, 11, 12},{19, 26, 30},{2, 27, 29},{1, 28, 29, 30},{8, 16, 29},{6, 10, 30},{19, 21, 27},{1, 2, 3, 22}};
    int i;
    const char *color[30];

    for(i=1;i<31;i++)
        color[i]="white";

    for(i=1;i<31;i++)
        if(!strcmp(color[i],"white"))
            dfsvisit(a,i,color);

    return 0;

}
```

Just want to make sure if I am using `const char c` correct? If yes, where else have I done the mistake? I am trying to run it on codeblocks. It compiles well, but when I try to run it, it shows program has stopped working.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you check the braces in this line? `int a[][30]={{1, 2}},{4, 8},{5, 16, 21}};`

Comment: In fact, could you just copy/paste some _working_ code, please, instead of typing it in? That would save all of us a lot of work...

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
for(i=1;i<=30;u++)
```

to:

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
```

Comment: What Paul R meant was: "Edit your question and correct the `u` typo to the `i` it should be."

Comment: @imaginatives: `c[30]` is valid only for indices from 0 to 29. If you iterate until i == 30 then you will be attempting to access beyond the bounds of `c[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing pointers to constant strings, which may or may not be equal when the strings are equal. Use an `enum` for this kind of algorithm:

```
enum { BLACK, GRAY, WHITE };
```

Comment: Ok, will try. Where did you see -1?

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer seconds after I posted it. Then someone else upvoted it, so it's now at 0. (Not referring to your program.)

Answer (score 2):

You say that this:

`for(i=1;i<=30;u++)`

compiles?

I suggest changing the `u` to an `i`...

**EDIT:**
OK, so you say the `u` was a typo.
Next step: start the thing in a debugger, wait for it to loop, break into it and step through.
That should tell you where something happens to your loop variable.

**EDIT 2:**
< niggle >
I second everybody who suggests you use std::string. You might consider dropping the irregular arrays in favor of `std::vector`s of `std::vector`s, which, through the use of iterators, would have caught the [fencepost error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fencepost_error) in your loop for you. In general, the STL `vector` is safer and more comfortable than an array while being just as fast and small.
And while were at it, it is best practice to declare your loop variables within the `for` instead of at the beginning of the function scope ([RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)). Unless, of course, you need that value *after* the loop.
< /niggle >

**EDIT 3:**
For more on std::string, std::vector and std::otherStuff: the book [Accelerated C++](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/) gives a good introduction to C++ and especially the STL. Concepts like `char*` or arrays only come up quite late, after the STL-way of doing things has been safely covered and practiced. I'd really like to see something like that for the Boost library...

Comment: Oh sorry that was a typo, its  `i` only.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your for loop is incorrect, it should be like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 30; i++)
```

Second, your array `int a[][30]` should be like `int a[30][]` (30 elements of 2, 3 or 4 integers).

Third, you can't pass an array like this, use a pointer.

Well, this code is not clear, and the recursive function could make a stack overflow.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use strcmp instead of == for your string comparison.

However, it's not clear why this would hang. You've removed the code that could have this go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not correctly using C style strings (`char *`).  Give it up and use `std::string` instead.

For example:

```
const char *color[30];

for(i=1;i<31;i++)
    color[i]="white";
```

The above fragment copies **pointers** and does not make duplicates of the text.  This may or may not be what you wanted.

Rewritten more safely:

```
const char * color[30]; // 30 pointers to char.
const char text_white[] = "white";

for (i = 0; i < 30; ++i)  // Note addition of spaces
{
   color[i] = text_white;
}
```

The `const char text_white[]` declares a pointer, `text_white`, to constant data.  This will let the compiler know when you try to assign to the literal.

The C++ code for this:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> Text_Container;
Text_Container texts;
const std::string white_text("white");
const unsigned int MAX_TEXTS = 30;
for (i = 0; i < MAX_TEXTS; ++i)
{
    texts[i] = white_text;  // Makes a copy of the string.
}
```

Give up on `char *` for text unless your program **needs** to conserve memory.  Prefer `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Comment: Is it necessary to define `const unsigned int MAX_TEXTS = 30;`? Cant I directly use 30 and how will spaces make a difference?

Comment: Can you suggest some good link to study about std::string? Thanks.

Comment: The above code is not working, it says expected initializer before < and Text_container not declared in this scope.

Comment: @imaginatives: You need to `#include <string>`

Comment: @imaginatives, search the web for "program magic numbers".  You'll find out later in your efforts how simple it is to change one constant (the named identifer) rather than tracking down the number 30, verifying it is the number to change, and modifying all instances.